# How to get PC hardware IDs using any way using browser (e.e. javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, get, virtual-machine, hardware

I searched but couldn't find answer.

I want to get Hardware IDs from PC using browser only to generate a unique code.
So even when user use virtual PC. I can detect them via Hardware because they can not change their hardware's identity.

Applications can easily do it but is there any possible way to do same with flash application, java/javascript or browswer add one etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way is to write a browser plugin - if you require a hardware id from the user then it reasonable to be explicit about this with the user and require them to install the plugin first.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript, you can't access the MAC address of the machine, which is probably the closest thing to a "hardware id".

Java and Flash are being deprecated in the browser too, so while I'm sure an option exists there, many users won't be able to use them very soon.

I think a good solution would be to have a server assign a unique ID to a user, which is then stored as in a cookie on the user's machine.